# Make a tables join - if value in joining table is in multiple values in the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which look like this:

| ID | SOME_DATA_FIRST_TABLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 22 |
| 2 | 32 |
| 3 | 45 |

| ID | SOME_DATA_SECOND_TABLE |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3,4,5,6 | 99 |
| 5,6,7,8,9,11 | 31 |
| 56,67,88,45,11 | 87 |

How can I make a join between tables which would like:

SELECT *
FROM first_table as ft,
JOIN second_table as st,
on <if ft.ID (for example 1) is inside of the values in the column from the second table (for example 1,2,3,4,5,6) then it should make a join between tables.
How such a syntax should look like?
I couldn't find any similar thread, and couldn't find any solution to it.

Comment: I guess, you can start from topics like "String split in MySQL" to split IDs in the second table

Comment: Comma delimited data structure in second table is not "friendly" for querying (i.e. reporting). You have to parse and split those ids  each time you query then, hitting performance.
If it possible at all, I would recommend to reconsider data structure and introduce in-between table with split ids.

Comment: _There is no syntax for this_, because the schema is **broken**; it cries out for an additional table. It's _NEVER_ okay to put delimited data in a single column like that. You might find a work-around, but they tend to be awkward and SLOW, because indexes on the delimited field are worthless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to normalize your data, the performance and database management would be better and easier.

As per the question you could use FIND_IN_SET:

```
select t1.ID,
       t1.SOME_DATA_FIRST_TABLE,
       t2.ID,
       t2.SOME_DATA_SECOND_TABLE
from table1 t1  
inner join table2 t2  ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.ID,t2.ID);
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> ID    SOME_DATA_FIRST_TABLE         ID         SOME_DATA_SECOND_TABLE
> 1           22                1,2,3,4,5,6         99
> 2           32                1,2,3,4,5,6         99
> 3           45                1,2,3,4,5,6         99
> ```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfPmXs4tK39kPwjincMhJY/0)